# To which first-person game does this screenshot of a mountain lift belong?

Tags: game-identification

Recently I found a screenshot on my old computer. I can't remember how the game is called, but I can remember that I'd like it and now I would like to play it again. I just can't find the name. I think obviously it has to be a rather old egoshooter

[image: Mountain Lift with enemy soldiers]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That would be [Return to Castle Wolfenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Castle_Wolfenstein).